# Why can't my website (in Wordpress) be accessed?

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

I have my own tiny blog that is built on top of Wordpress.
I know how to code HTML and CSS, and I can fairly understand some php.

I wonder why this happens to my site:

-When I use the browser's url bar,write down my website address and press enter. I see my site as an empty website. When I view it's source, I see a script with math functions.

-**BUT**... When I open and go to my site by clicking a link like this one: [imraven](http://imraven.com)
It seems to be working well and I'll arrive to my site with no issue.

Now, my question is that why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Here are some details:
-I used Mozilla Firefox and Chrome.
-It has the same issue even when I try switching to another theme.

Thanks!

Comment: The script at the top of the source code is not valid - `<script>` tags need to be inside the `<head>` or `<body>`, and this one is outside of the `<html>` tag altogether. But the real question is what it's doing there in the first place - it looks like malicious script. Do you know where it came from?

Comment: The script that appears in the source is the result of an exploit attack. You can read more about it [here](http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/blackhat-lounge/412682-wp-site-injected-can-anyone-decipher-code-me.html). You should ensure that you have the newest Wordpress version to prevent these type of exploits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My browser (Opera) tells me the following:

> Visiting this page may be harmful. It has been reported for
> distributing malicious software.
>
> Opera Software strongly discourages visiting this page.

Check for viruses and malware installed on your site and for the love of everything good, keep Wordpress up-to-date if you haven't done so.

Comment: Woah! I just updated my wordpress and it worked! haha... I wonder what have happened to my wordpress. Well thanks anyway :)  I'll check your answer once the check answer is enabled.

Comment: @Raven Just updating Wordpress won't be enough; your site is contaminated, and that has to be solved. I'll try to find what your site has been infected with.

Comment: @Raven Hey wow, it seems just upgrading Wordpress *did* work to remove the malware, I can't seem to find it in the source anymore. Anyway, you're probably better of if you change your passwords and check your logs.

Comment: Yeah, I'm amazed too... Well, I'll change my admin details from now on. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`imraven.com` is not the same as `www.imraven.com`, which I assume is what you're typing. If you want your site to work from the `www` subdomain, you'll need to configure the server accordingly.

Comment: well, it's still the same.. The issue is still there.

Comment: @Raven as mentioned in another answer, it looks like your sever has been compromised. Viewing the source of `www.imraven.com` reveals what appears to be a malicious script with an obfuscated payload.

Answer (score 1):

You're still hacked: http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/imraven.com

See [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/) and [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress) and tell your host. Change all passswords. Scan your own PC.